What is the difference between "up for it" and "down for it"
I was watching a movie and I was expecting the next dialog to be "Are you up for it?".  Instead it was "Are you down for it?"
They both sound correct and I have heard both often.  Is there a difference between them?

I have the sense that up for can involve being ready for, having the energy for, and similar notions involving ability, whereas down for is used only for desire. Thus I’m not up for a walk, my feet hurt but Given her sweet tooth, she’s always down for dessert.

It's just the difference between I will stand up and be seen to be willing to participate and You can put me down on the list of people willing to participate. Basically, no difference worth talking about (except this use of I'm down for it is more recent and imho more "slangy").

Both "Are you up for it" and "Are you down for it" mean roughly the same thing, that is, are you interested in doing a proposed activity. Further shades of intent or meaning may exist for individual speakers, but I haven't noticed a consistent pattern between, say, desire toward an activity and commitment to an activity.
"Are you up for it" may be more common. In a Corpus of Contemporary American English search, "Are you up for it" (the exact clause) came up 21 times, usually in spoken dialogue on shows or films like Seinfeld, ER, Buffy the Vampire Slayer, Army Wives, Fresh Air, and CBS This Morning.
"Are you down for it" received 0 results; the more general "Are you down?" (expressing interest, and excluding the literal "Are you down here?" or "Are you down there?") had 57 results, again mostly from shows or films. Only a couple included "Are you down for" something, like "So, my brother, are you down for this Saturday, Dune Buggies "R" Us?" from Beverly Hills, 90210.
Repeating a similar search in NOW Corpus, "Are you up for it" received 91 results. "Are you down for" received 26 results (including one "Are you down for it?").
In other words, the reason you may have expected "Are you up for it" is because that has been used more frequently around you.

Perhaps a better comparison is between I'm up / down for it, where you can at least see the less common down version starting to gain some traction. Note that I've also included your Are you up for it? on that NGram usage chart, because it's almost as common as I'm up for it, but Are you down for it? simply doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart.

We say down for that .
